# horizontally center various width slick.js slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is there a way to horizontally center slides that have a `max-height` set with various widths using slick.js? Notice in the url below how they are floated to the left leaving an empty space to the right of each slide.

Here's is an example: http://valeriebischoff.com/staging/work/post-soviet-estonia/#feature

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to go about it, pick one

1) Remove `max-height` from `.slick-slide`

2) Add a `min-width` to `.slick-slide` and add `overflow:hidden` on the parent container.

3) Change from using an `<img>` tag to a `<div`> and set the image as the background, with the property `background-size:cover`